# Animation for Placeholder Not Running

Tags: css, sass, css-animations

I have an animation setup to alternate between 0 and 100 opacity. When applying it to just the input it works fine.
But when I try to apply it to the `placeholder` selector for the input it does not.

The curious thing is if I put the css attribute for opacity directly in the `placeholder` SCSS class it works fine.

```
input {
  &:focus::placeholder {
    animation: blinkPlaceholder 2s ease-out -2s infinite alternate forwards;
  }

  @keyframes blinkPlaceholder {
    0% {
      opacity: 100;
    }

    49% {
      opacity: 100;
    }

    50% {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

I couldn't figure out how to get the built in editor to work with SCSS, so here is a jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ov1hbd65/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution (albeit the code is very picky).

You have to use a different method of animation. Further more the `-moz` and `-webkit` styles have to be in their own blocks or they will be deemed invalid by Firefox.

Finally, the `:placeholder-shown` selector is used so that these styles don’t affect the text. Without that selector any style applied to the placeholder will also apply to the text once typed in.

```css
input:placeholder-shown[placeholder]
{
    opacity: 1;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: initial;
}
input:placeholder-shown::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    opacity: 1;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: initial;
}
input:placeholder-shown::-moz-placeholder {
    opacity: 1;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: initial;
}
input:placeholder-shown:focus[placeholder]
{
    opacity: 1;
    color: inherit;
    animation: anim 1s infinite;
}
input:placeholder-shown:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    opacity: 1;
    color: inherit;
    animation: anim 1s infinite;
}
input:placeholder-shown:focus::-moz-placeholder{
    opacity: 1;
    color: inherit;
    animation: anim 4s infinite;
}

@keyframes anim {
    0% { color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); }
    49% { color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); }
    50% { color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3); }
    100% { color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3); }
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Test"/>
```